# Are there any classic fantasy type comic series? (with dwarves, magic, etc)

Tags: comics, fantasy-genre, dwarves

I'm starting to get into comics and am reading some of the big ones, marvel, dc and I've seen the fantasy world in Grimm Fairy Tales. But I was expecting to be able to find something like a classic fantasy with Dwarves, Dragons, Wizards. Along the lines of forgotten realms, tolkien, warhammer, etc those type of worlds in comic book form.

Its such a big genre in novels and graphically there is lots work with, yet I can't seem to find comics set in such a world. Are there comic series like that, either ongoing or completed and what would be a good way to find them?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. Unfortunately this sort of question (unbounded lists of recommendations) is off-topic here. When you have a [bit more rep](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) (and there are [lots of ways](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to earn rep), you'll be able to pose this question in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), which is a much better place for these sorts of discussions

Comment: Incidentally, there have been several iterations of "Dungeons and Dragons" comics, which might help scratch your itch, including ones set in the Forgotten Realms.

Comment: Question was meant more along the lines of 'do these comics exist: Yes/No' and how do you find them 'Go to X,Y' wasn't expecting list of recommendations back. But I see your point, will ask on a different site.

Comment: the european (especially french) market has some incredible comics (well, rather larger format, going for a few volumes. known as belgian/french as many well known are from belgium, others from france, and most of those are in french). For exemple "la quête de l'oiseau du temps" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Qu%C3%AAte_de_l%27oiseau_du_temps ). translations exists

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are some currently being published -

Dynamite publish [comics](http://paizo.com/store/byCompany/d/dynamiteEntertainment/pathfinderComics) set in the Pathfinder universe.
Collected in a number of hardcovers, including -
1: [Dark Waters Rising](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pathfinder-Dark-Waters-Rising-Dynamite/dp/1606903926/)
2: [Of Tooth and Claw](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pathfinder-2-Tooth-Claw-HC/dp/1606904949/)
3: [City of Secrets](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pathfinder-3-City-Secrets-Genzoman/dp/160690602X/)
4: [Origins](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pathfinder-4-Origins-Kevin-Stokes/dp/1606907840/) (forthcoming)

Failing that, there is also Birthright, but that crosses over into the "real" world.
1: [Homecoming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Birthright-1-Homecoming-Joshua-Williamson/dp/1632152312/)

Then there's comics based around other properties such as D&D and Magic: The Gathering, but I'm not aware of any currently being published monthly. (Trade collections undoubtedly available.)

As to a good way to find others, sites such as [Comic List](http://www.comiclist.com/index.php) provide the releases for each week.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai and Sean, that's what I was looking for, I think the sheer volume of marvel and dc floods the results when I was trying to do searches without knowing how to phrase it.